# python subprocess throws error "no such file or direcrory"

Tags: python, subprocess

```
s=subprocess.Popen(['/home/karthik/Downloads/stanford-parser-2011-06-08/lexparser.csh','-'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1213, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm sure this file exists and open() with this filename works.Why am i getting this error ? i use python 2.7

Comment: Obviously it does not exist. Should we trust the error message of Python or your claim?

Comment: f=open("/home/karthik/Downloads/stanford-parser-2011-06-08/lexparser.csh","r").This works perfectly fine

Comment: do you have a #! (shebang) at the beginning of the file you try to execute pointing to a command which does not exist ?

(or in other words, can you execute the same command by hand ?)

Comment: i'm running this command in the python interpreter ,so should be adding a shebang?

Comment: I mean, what's at the beginning of `lexparser.csh` ?

Comment: yes there is a shebang present : #!/bin/csh -f

Comment: When I run `lexparser.csh` from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml on the command line I get: `./lexparser.csh: bad interpreter: /bin/csh: no such file or directory`. I would first have to install csh/tcsh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `csh` is installed and is in `/bin/csh` (otherwise edit the command after the shebang in `lexparser.sh`).